# Alternating between lines in a opened text file to store into a generated note

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a script that can read a text file and generate notes based on the lines inside the file, the problem is every time i generate a ex_note it puts the first sentence on the front AND back of the note. I would like to alternate and put one line in front, the next line in back, create the note and then empty the strings and go to the next line and do it all over again until no more lines are left in the file and all cards are created. Also appending each generated note to the collection list.

```
def build():
    with codecs.open("Sentences.txt", 'r', encoding='utf_8') as fileopen:

        collection = []
        front = ""
        back = ""

        for line in fileopen:
            front += line
            back += line

            ex_note = Note(
                    model=ex_model,
                    fields=[front, back])
            collection.append(ex_note)
            front = front.replace(front,"")
            back = back.replace(back,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of line numbers using `enumerate`, and set even lines as `front` and odd lines as `back`

```py
def build():
    with codecs.open("Sentences.txt", 'r', encoding='utf_8') as fileopen:

        collection = []
        front = ""
        back = ""

        for line_number, line in enumerate(fileopen):
            if line_number % 2 == 0:
                # even rows
                front = line
            else:
                # odd rows
                back = line
                ex_note = Note(
                        model=ex_model,
                        fields=[front, back])
                collection.append(ex_note)
```

Note that you don't need to clear the values of `front` and `back` every iteration, as they will be automatically reassigned

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using zip?

```
def build():
    with codecs.open("Sentences.txt", 'r', encoding='utf_8') as fileopen:
        collection = []
        front = ""
        back = ""
        my_list = [line for line in fileopen]
        for front, back in zip(my_list, my_list[1:]): 
            ex_note = Note(
                    model=ex_model,
                    fields=[front, back])
            collection.append(ex_note)
```